# Displaying Quill editor content with correct style

Tags: quill, ngx-quill

I am using the Quill editor (via ngx-quill) to give my user the ability to edit documents.  When the documents are displayed I show them like this:

```
  <div [innerHTML]="doc.text"></div>
```

This works reliably, but the styling of the content of the `div` tag is quite different from what you see in the Quill editor window.  What I want to do is apply the Quill content stylesheet to my `div` tag, but I haven't been able to find any document to do that.  Does anyone here know how to do that?

I know one alternative is to invoke a Quill editor in read-only mode and without a tool-bar.  That's my fall-back but I would prefer not to do that.

Comment: May be you can look [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill#quillviewhtmlcomponent---using-angular-innerhtml).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Some inline styles are displayed, but the styles applied from the Quill.js class are not applied. `post-content` is class of `div` containing the content:

```
let content=document.querySelector('.post-content')
 content.innerHTML=content.innerText
```

Comment: So, did that selector fix the issue for you then?